# Is this a good approach for developing a multi-layered C/C++ application using docker?

Tags: c++, docker

I am in the high-level design phase of a new project where we are seriously considering to use docker to build an embedded application. The application shall run on an ARM device with an embedded Linux distribution.

The application will have different layers (architecturally, not necessarily in the docker sense). The layers are to be managed more or less independently, which each having their own versioning.

The application is to be written in C++. For the sake of the question, let's pretend the bottom layer is implemented as a shared library and the top layer is an executable that uses the library.

I am struggling with how to build the layers, such that the images are as small as possible.

My current idea is to use make a docker image for each architectural layer. I think I should use multi-stage building to keep the build tooling outside of the images.

The docker file for the bottom layer now looks like this:

```
# Stage #1: build

FROM gcc as build



WORKDIR /build

# copy and compile source files

COPY *.c *.h ./

RUN gcc -shared -fPIC -o libmylib.so mylib.c



# Stage 2

FROM gcr.io/distroless/cc

# copy build artefacts to image

COPY --from=build /build/libmylib.so /usr/lib/

COPY --from=build /build/mylib.h /usr/include/
```

And for the second layer:

```
# 'dummy' from to get access to headers/libs of bottom layer in build layer

FROM mylib as mylib



FROM gcc as build



WORKDIR /build

# copy source files for this layer

COPY *.c ./



# copy headers and libraries from mylib - I DON'T LIKE THIS

COPY --from=mylib /usr/lib/libmylib.so /usr/lib

COPY --from=mylib /usr/include/mylib.h /usr/include



RUN gcc -o hello hello.c -lmylib



# Stage 3: create executable image

FROM mylib

COPY --from=build /build/hello /



# run main executable

CMD ["./hello"]
```

This results in a relatively small image that contains both the library and the main executable and does not contain any build tools. So this meets my needs.

But I don't like in this solution, that the second dockerfile must know the names of all files that it uses of the bottom layer, because it needs to copy them to its build stage. It would be more elegant if the build stage could be based on ("FROM") the library image, so that all artefacts would already be present. But this would mean I would have to pull in all build tooling into this stage...

Is the way I am approaching this the generally accepted way of doing it? I would like to hear of best practices of building multi-layered applications in docker..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one “bottom layer” that installs locally built shared libraries, you might consider building two Docker images out of it.  One has a complete set of development tools, plus your library, and its header files; the other has a minimal set of runtime libraries, plus your library, and no header files.

```sh
# I am Dockerfile.builder
FROM gcc
WORKDIR /usr/src/mylib
COPY . .
RUN make && make install && ldconfig
```

```sh
# I am Dockerfile.runtime
FROM ubuntu
COPY --from=myname/builder /usr/lib/mylib.so* /usr/lib
RUN ldconfig
```

Have your CI system build *both* of these.  Note that the second one depends on the first (`myname/builder` is whatever image name you’re using for the first image).

Now when you build your application, you have a base Docker image with your local build tools and libraries, plus a base Docker image with the library preinstalled.

```sh
FROM myname/builder AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN make && make install

FROM myname/runtime
COPY --from=build /usr/local/bin/app /usr/local/bin/app
CMD ["app"]
```

This approach won’t work well if you have multiple shared libraries that you’re trying to separately build and install (as a corollary to the more general rule that you can’t combine two independent Docker images).

Another generically useful approach (that works in pretty much all languages) is to package your library without using Docker.  If you’re using something like an Ubuntu runtime, you can package your library into Debian packages.  This has a split between development and runtime packages, so in your builder image you can `apt install` the development version (with header files) and at runtime only the runtime version (with usr the shared library).  Similar approaches work for npm and Python packages, Ruby gems, ....

Comment: Thanks, your advice to use two dockerfiles to separate the build and run-time artefacts is exactly the sort of solution I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

As C/C++ are more appropriate for low level development I wouldn't recommend docker to use. Instead you can choose GO with Docker which probably you can achieve the same.

Comment: The application is of the embedded type, so we do need a low level programming language.

Comment: GO it's low level too!